# Splice item out of ng-repeat array, when that item is clicked

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click, splice

I have an array of items that I'm repeating.

```
<li ng-repeat="lineItem in lineItems" class="bouncy-slide-left">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-5 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 pad-right">
        <label for="expenses">{{lineItem.labels.name}}Expense:</label>
        <br>
        <select name="expenses" ng-model="expense.name" class="form-control" style="width: 175px;">
            <option value="{{expense.name}}" ng-repeat="expense in expenses">{{expense.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-5 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 pad-right">
        <label>Material Cost:</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" ng-model="expense.cost" class="form-control" name="material" placeholder="5.00">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-5 col-lg-2  col-xl-2 pad-right">
        <label>Quantity:</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" ng-model="expense.quantity" class="form-control" name="quantity" placeholder="5">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-5 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 pad-right">
        <label>Labor Rate:</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" ng-model="expense.labor" class="form-control" name="labor" placeholder="20.00">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-5 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 pad-right">
        <label>Hours:</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" ng-model="expense.hours" class="form-control" name="hours" placeholder="4">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-5 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 pad-right">
        <label>Responsible:</label>
        <br>
        <span>Renter</span>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-1">
        <span>Owner</span>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-1">
    </div>

    <br>
    <div class="col-sm-12 pad-right">
        <span class="pad-right">Owner Total: {{ownerTotal}}</span>
        <span class="pad-right">Renter Total: {{renterTotal}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12  pad-right">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="addExpense()"><i class="fa-check"></i>Add New Expense</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="removeExpense($event)"><i class="fa-remove"></i>Remove Expense</button>
    </div>
</li>
```

I have an array, an add method, and a remove method.

```
 $scope.lineItems = [
    {expense: 1}
];

//when button is clicked
//add a new blank object to the lineItems array
$scope.addExpense = function() {
    var num = Math.random();
    var item = {expense: num};
    $scope.lineItems.push(item);
};

//when remove button is clicked 
  //remove the specific item that was clicked from the array
$scope.removeExpense = function($event) {    
    var elm = $event.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement;
    console.log(elm);
    elm.remove();
    //need to splice selected item OUT of the array
    var i = ???
    $scope.lineItems.splice(i, 1);
};
```

I've tried several things here.  Most of the answers I've found just use indexOf, however the items are being dynamically generated by my model.  So I don't know how to get an index of something that doesn't exist yet.

I've also tried some jQueryLite.  I would love to just use  something like : when $this is clicked, remove it from the dom.  I can't seem to find the ANGULAR answer for that.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `ng-click="removeExpense($event)"` simply pass the `lineItem`, like `ng-click="removeExpense(lineItem)"`.  You can then find the `lineItem` in `lineItems` by `indexOf`

```
$scope.removeExpense = function(lineItem) {
   var index = $scope.lineItems.indexOf(lineItem);
   $scope.lineItems.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that worked! For some reason I couldn't visualize the lineItem working as a parameter.  Also, do you have any suggestions on my add method.  Right now, i'm just using random numbers to avoid a 'duplicate key' issue.

Comment: Assuming I understand what your problem is, make your `ng-repeat` be `ng-repeat="lineItem in lineItems track by $index"` and then it won't matter if there are dupes or not, @JoshPMP

Answer (score 0):

call `removeExpense($index)` on `ng-click` like:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="removeExpense($index)"><i class="fa-remove"></i>Remove Expense</button>
```

and replace remove function with this code:

```
$scope.removeExpense = function(index) {
   $scope.lineItems.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: That is dangerous: if the array is filtered, the $index of the ng-repeat won't match with the index in the array.